# Error: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error after trying to insert values into a MySQL table.

> Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `first_name` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

PHP:

```
$query = "
        INSERT INTO 
            users (username, password, first_name, last_name, salt, email) 
            VALUES (:username, :password, :first_name, :last_name :salt, :email) ";

    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        ':last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
        ':salt' => $salt, 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    );

    try { 
        // Execute the query to insert user into table
        $statement = $database->prepare($query); 
        $result = $statement->execute($query_params); 
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Insert failed".$ex->getMessage();
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
```

I don't understand the problem and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing comma:

```
[..snip..]:first_name, :last_name :salt, :email) ";
                                 ^---
```

And since you are missing that `,`, there's only 5 values available for your 6-field `INSERT`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks a bunch!